# Display Address/LatLng of Building User is Looking at with Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

I was just wondering if it's possible to get the coordinates or address of a building that a user is looking at with Glass. I have access to a pair so I'm trying to flesh out some ideas, and I have one that I'm really interested in, but I'm not sure if it'd be possible yet. I kind of figured I could do something similar to taking the location of the user from their phone and the direction they're facing with Glass to search my database of coordinates to see if they're looking in the general direction of a LatLng pair that I would like to place a marker on, but if there's a pre-built function for that then I'd like to use it :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The location information you will get from Google Glass is for the device itself (usually obtained from  the paired phone).  There are no pre-built functions that try to extrapolate the location of something that the camera is pointed at in Google Glass.

Comment: @Erstwhilelll Unrelated - is there a way to tell which direction the glass is looking? (ie, 'glass is facing south' or in degrees, etc?)

Comment: @Abraxas you might check out https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors which describes sensor usage (rotation, gyroscope, magnetism sensors ARE present) but you will have to do some math.  Sensor support is at API 17 level only.